# Error message when deleting folders/files on Maintenance mode

Tags: files, maintenance-mode

I turn the site in maintenance mode for update Drupal Core from 7.30 to 7.32. I follow the step on [Drupal docmentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290) to delete all folders and files, beside "site" folder(on step 5). However, I got the error message and warning about missing files. I dont think that how maintenace mode should be. What am i missing?

PS:
1. the site does show in maintenance mode before I delete all the folders and files(beside site folder)
2. Site back to normal after copying v7.32 folders and files(beside site folder)

Comment: What exactly you did, step by step? And what you expected? If you delete files, and before you will upload new ones, you will have missing files. That's pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @Mołot I followed all the steps in Update Drupal Core Documentation(https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290). The only issue I have is step 5. I got an error message instead of maintenance mode until I copy all the new files back. I thought the whole process would be in maintenance mode.

Comment: "I got an error message instead of maintenance mode until I copy all the new files back." - that's expected - you deleted Drupal, and there was not enough of it left to handle even maintenance mode. That's why in pro environments things like that are made differently, with second (virtual) server and so on.

Comment: @Mołot Do you know what is the purpose to put site in maintenance mode while update the Drupal Core?

Comment: Yes. To prevent changes from happening in the meantime. Imagine someone adds new content, or fills multistep form. What happen if you delete PHP file right before it is needed? You can end up with inconsistent data in database. You don't want that. Maintenance mode is the best simple way to prevent it. Even in two-machine upgrade scenario I turn on maintenance mode on machine that's going to get upgrades - and this machine is not visible to anyone but me, my boss and our admins.

Comment: @Mołot Thank you Mołot. I never thought about that. It would be nice if the maintenance mode still on while deleting these files.

Comment: @CocoSkin It would be nice, but where would the page be generated when you have deleted all the files?

Comment: To be fair though, it wouldn't hurt for the instructions to mention that this will happen.

Comment: @Letharion At first, I thought the maintenance mode will not load any data but the maintenance message. Which I'm wrong and should be very simple. In the future before deleting files, I should replace the index.php with simple html table & messages.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. "will not load any data but the maintenance message". What code would load that message? Where would the message be stored? _all_ the basic logic is deleted. But yes, sticking a new file in place is a useful workaround.

Comment: What I would recommend though, is that you look at git. If you do the update through git, the update will take milliseconds, and no one will ever even notice the site was missing.

Comment: @Letharion ty for the recommendation. I will take a look at git.

Comment: if git isn't an option, something else simple you can do is to create a static index.php which holds a 'maintenance mode' layout and message - copy it over first so that any calls to the server go through it, then delete everything except /sites and index.php

Answer (score 2):

Rather than the two step deleting the folders and then uploading the new ones, I would recommend just copying over the old ones with new ones. You'll probably have to tell your FTP program to overwrite but when I upgrade in this fashion, I select all the files and directories **except for sites folder** and push them to the server.

When possible, I use the Drush tool via a terminal window as it is a much quicker and easier solution.

Comment: not sure about this. There must be a reason why the Update Drupal Core Documentation says to delete all these files. It’s possible the new and old Drupal has different amount of files?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure about that either except perhaps for thoroughness. Most FTP client programs I've used will prompt you to overwrite a file or directory if it already exists so maybe the folks at Drupal.org were concerned about confusing the issue. If you delete a folder and then upload the new one, there is less chance of confusion in that regard.

Comment: There's (at least two risks). One is that if the update gets "half done", you have no way to tell, and might not even know. Instead you end up with odd and hard to reproduce bugs because you run some sort of 7.31 and half chimera. The other is that the update might require the removal of some file, so again, you end up with parts of the previous version, that may cause problems in the new version. In most cases it will all work just fine though, but the official guide has to be careful.